# Statistical significance for analysis/inference with PCA

Tags: statistical-significance, pca

I've got the following comment from a peer reviewer:

> the interpretations of PCA were described in not objective manner. The PC values can be statistically accessed and everything should be discussed with statistically significance or not.

I wonder how my PCA outputs can be endowed with statistical significance... I performed a varimax rotated PCA with SPSS and I got the loads for every PC (2) and the scores for the samples (157). Then I plotted them and saw 3 clear sample "clusters". I discussed which were the main variables loading every PC and then explained the characteristics of every "cluster" according to their relation with every PC. Whether the reviewer asks for "statistics"....*what can I do*?

- **Can I perform any statistics to guarantee which variables are loading "significantly" my PCs?**
- **Can I do any test to check whether the samples groups are really different (discriminate samples by using statistics)?**

Comment: I use to coauthor papers in medical journals where I am one of many authors but I am the one that did the statistics.  Typically these journal did not have a statistician reviewing the statistics.  When non-statisticians do the reviewing they are often off base and they ask you to do something that makes no sense.  This makes answering the reviewer problematic.

Comment: Thank you, Michael!!! ...how do you think I can reply to the reviewer in a polite way? do you have any fancy reference to be provided, please? THANKS!